# Not able to import openzeplin/contract and use it in my solidity code?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, openzeppelin

I have successfully installed openzeppelin/contracts, but I am unable to import it. It shows me an error which is

> Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the @openzeppelin/contracts is installed in Correct Directory..

Also What npm version of @openzeppelin/contracts you have installed ?  The positon of OpenZepplin Contracts is changed after version 4..

Refer..

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/openzeppelin-contracts-ownership-ownable-sol-not-found/16229/3

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/error-importing-openzeppelin-contracts-in-vscode/6971/11

Answer (score 0):

Simplest hack:

CTRL + SHIFT + P -> Reload Window

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I will try and provide an answer in the context in which I understood it as I also face similar issue.

```
"@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol"
```

The import form above works well for solidity version 0.6.x but if you are using solidity version ^0.8.x it doesn't work.

This is how I resolved the issue.
First install openzeppelin with the npm installer:

```
npm i @openzeppelin/contracts
```

The command above will install the current version of openzeppelin. At the time of writing this, the current version is 4.x.
After the install is successful import openzeppelin this way:

```
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

That is the directory where npm installed it.

I hope this helps someone.